# Magento 2 - Import Product .csv via CLI

Tags: magento2, import, cli, product-import

Actually, the desired requirement is quite simple.
I would like to control and execute the import from the backend of the Magento 2 system via the CLI.

This question was asked some time ago (2016) here.
However, I use the Community Edition and the free version of the Firebear plugin cannot do this.
https://github.com/firebearstudio/importexportfree

Is it possible to start the product import with "Add Update" (all other default) via the CLI?

I hope you can help me. :)

Current System: Ubuntu 18.04 MariaDB Magento 2.3.1 (CE)

Comment: If you just want to import product prices via CLI, you can try this extension: https://www.magepsycho.com/magento2-mass-regular-special-tier-group-price-importer.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to start the product import with "Add Update" (all other default) via the CLI?

The short answer is no.  You would write something custom to do this.

Writing console scripts is relatively easy to do.  Take a look at this answer.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/220791/70343